# I get a query loop on the service provider.. is this an N+1 problem? because I'm experiencing slow down on the web

Tags: laravel

I still can't solve this problem...? here I attach a picture of the debugbar and the service provider code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dntVu.jpg)

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $appName = config('app.name');

        if (preg_match_all('/\b(\w)/', strtoupper($appName), $value))
            $acronymAppName = implode('', $value[1]);

        $view
            ->with('appName', $appName)
            ->with('acronymAppName', $acronymAppName);

        if (strpos(url()->current(), 'admin') !== false && strpos(url()->current(), 'print') === false) {
            $logo = General::where('type', 'logo')->first();
            $path = $logo->content;

            $unprocessedPesanan = ViewPesanan::whereNotIn('status_pesanan_id', [
                Pesanan::STATUS_SELESAI,
                Pesanan::STATUS_DIBATALKAN
            ])
                ->groupBy('status_pesanan_id')
                ->get([
                    'status_pesanan_id',
                    DB::raw("SUM(1) as total")
                ])
                ->pluck('total', 'status_pesanan_id');
```

I'm very grateful if anyone can provide input on this issue

Comment: ServiceProvider is used to bootstrap application services. I don't think that you should make DB requestes there. On the other hand, the query is probably slow because of data size (You are returning whole table - 2 rows, I guess the table has a lots of data if it takes 500ms to query one table).

Comment: is this issue resolved? let's troubleshoot

Comment: problem not resolved..